# Adding and removing classes on multiple dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've three dropdowns.. When i click on the div with the data-column="1" ( Momentum Jeans Shorts ), I want the current dropdown to remove the "active" & "disable" class for the data-column="1" (Momentum Shorts) and also add the "disable" & "active" class on the selected div which is the data-column="1" ( Momentum Jeans Shorts )..

On my second dropdown, I would want the data-column="1" (Momentum Shorts) to not have the "disable" & "active" class. data-column="2" ( Momentum Jeans Shorts ) would have the "disable" class.

I've tried to work on this many hours but I cant seems to get the algorithm right.. I've attached a screenshot of the dropdowns, and hopefully you get what I'm trying to achieve

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <div>
            <a class="dropdown" href="#">CHANGE SHORT</a>
            <ul>
            
            <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item  active disable" data-column="1" data-product="momentum-shorts">Momentum Shorts</div>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="1" data-product="momentum-shorts-2-0">Momentum Shorts 2.0</div>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="1" data-product="ease-linen-shorts">Ease Linen Shorts</div>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item " data-column="1" data-product="momentum-jeans-shorts">Momentum Jeans Shorts</div>
            </li>
            
            </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
            <a class="dropdown" href="#">CHANGE SHORT</a>
            <ul>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="2" data-product="momentum-shorts">Momentum Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item  active disable" data-column="2" data-product="momentum-shorts-2-0">Momentum Shorts 2.0</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="2" data-product="ease-linen-shorts">Ease Linen Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item " data-column="2" data-product="momentum-jeans-shorts">Momentum Jeans Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
            <a class="dropdown" href="#">CHANGE SHORT</a>
            <ul>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="3" data-product="momentum-shorts">Momentum Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item disable" data-column="3" data-product="momentum-shorts-2-0">Momentum Shorts 2.0</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item  active disable" data-column="3" data-product="ease-linen-shorts">Ease Linen Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                <div class="compare-filter-item " data-column="3" data-product="momentum-jeans-shorts">Momentum Jeans Shorts</div>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


$(function() {
            $(".compare-filter-item").on("click",function() {
                const column_value = $(this).attr("data-column");
                const selected_data_product = $(this).attr("data-product");

                $('.compare-filter-item[data-product="' + selected_data_product + '"][data-column="' + column_value + '"]').parent().parent().find(".active.disable").removeClass("active disable");


                $("[data-product='" + selected_data_product + "']").addClass("disable");
                $(this).addClass("active");

                const myarray = $(`.compare-all .compare-products [data-product="${selected_data_product}"]`).map(function() {
                return $(this).html();
                });

                $(`.compare-main .compare-products [data-column="${column_value}"]`)
                .each(function(i) { $(this).html(myarray[i]) });
            });
        });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Write the html as text please.

Comment: @Erenn sure! i've updated it!

Comment: Don't you think having both `.disable` and `.active` classes on an element a bit confusing? At this point I'm not confident about how I understand your question or how you expect it to work.

Comment: @zer00ne I was thinking of having the .disable so this buttons will be disabled from users clicking it.. while the .active is to have the active background color that its current selected on the dropdown... is this wrong?

I'm not sure if posting a link here is allowed.. but this is the website link im trying to follow the functionality on the 3 dropdowns ( CHANGE SHORT ) 

https://www.tenthousand.cc/pages/compare-shorts

Comment: It's just confusing, I think you want [mutually exclusive selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button), like a group of radio buttons.

Comment: @zer00ne the reason i even considered adding .disable & .active is because the site link i shared they added in "filter-disabled" & "filter-selected" which i think they work as the same mechanism as well.. im really stuck on multiple filters here

Comment: So basically these dropdowns give you 3 unique choices.

Comment: @zer00ne Correct! once a selection is selected, that option should not be available on other dropdowns as well

Comment: Ok, review my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566684/2813224)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior described in OP is called mutually exclusivity. Basically only one of a group can be selected, like radio buttons that share the same `[name]`.

**HTML**

First, assign a common class to all items:

```
<li><a href='#' class='link'></a></li>
```

Next, a "group" class for each set of 3 items that share the same position:

```
<!-- For example, each 2nd item of each dropdown -->
<li><a href='#' class='link x1'></a></li> // 1st dropdown
<li><a href='#' class='link x1'></a></li> // 2nd dropdown
<li><a href='#' class='link x1'></a></li> // 3rd dropdown
```

Then add a `data-*` attribute to each item, call it `data-group` and assign the same value as the new class:

```
<li><a href='#' class='link x1' data-group='x1'></a></li>
```

**CSS**

Two classes are needed:

```
.active {
  color: blue;
  background: goldenrod
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
}
```

**jQuery**

First, register all `.link` to the "click" event. When a `.link` is clicked...

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
  // Get the clicked .link's [data-group]
  const group = $(this).data('group');
  ...
```

Finally, make each `.link` able to `.toggle()` `.active` class on/off. If the clicked `.link` is `.active` then add `.disabled` to the other 2 items that share the same group, otherwise remove `.disabled` from the other 2 items:

```
...
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    $('.' + group).not(this).addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $('.' + group).removeClass('disabled');
  }
```

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});

$('.link').on('click', function() {
$(this).closest('ul').find('.link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.link').removeClass('disabled');
  $('ul').each(function() {
    activate(this);
  });
});

function activate(selector) {
  const act = $(selector).find('.active');
  if (act) {
    const group = $(act).data('group');
    $('.' + group).not(act).addClass('disabled');
  } 
  if (!act) {
    $('.' + group).removeClass('disabled');
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.15 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

menu {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a,
li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
  background: goldenrod
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <menu>
    <a href='#' class='trigger'>Xn</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x0' data-group='x0'>X0</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x1' data-group='x1'>X1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x2' data-group='x2'>X2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x3' data-group='x3'>X3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x4' data-group='x4'>X4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <a href='#' class='trigger'>Xn</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x0' data-group='x0'>X0</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x1' data-group='x1'>X1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x2' data-group='x2'>X2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x3' data-group='x3'>X3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x4' data-group='x4'>X4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <a href='#' class='trigger'>Xn</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x0' data-group='x0'>X0</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x1' data-group='x1'>X1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x2' data-group='x2'>X2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x3' data-group='x3'>X3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class='link x4' data-group='x4'>X4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution is really close on this one! However, the dropdown now allows multiple selections if they are not selected before. how if i want to just allow users to select one option instead of multiple in a single dropdown?

Comment: Do you mean 1 active per dropdown?

Comment: correct ! @zer00ne

Comment: Ok see update, it does as we discussed, I'll explain it later.